# Нужно ли вызывать clearInterval() для удаления таймера(setInterval) или достаточно вызвать return?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Интересует вопрос следует ли вызывать **clearInterval()** для удаления таймера или достаточно вызвать **return**.

Код:

```
function timeControl (time: number) { // требуется передать контекст

  let currentTime: number = time; // [seconds]
  timerLoop.bind(this)();

  let timer = setInterval( () => {


    if ( currentTime < 0 ){
      this.play   = false;
      this.stop   = true;
      this.finish = true;
      clearInterval(timer);
    }


    if ( this.play ) timerLoop.bind(this)();
    if ( this.stop ) { 
      this.timer.innerText = '00:00';
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
        
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Надо вызвать. Иначе память потечёт.

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления таймера следует вызывать `clearInterval()`.